# ZvP How to Defeat FFE?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to counter Protoss' fast expand as zerg?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24880/how-to-counter-protoss-fast-expand-as-zerg)

Lately I have had trouble while playing Zerg defeating a Forge Fast Expander. The trouble is that I can't break his walls quickly or easily. I have tried searching for strategies online about breaking a FFE however no good results appeared. I did beat one by using a Nydus canal but the player wasn't quick enough to respond and surely could have defeated it if given a few extra seconds.

**So what are some good strategies to defeating a Forge Fast Expander as Zerg?**

Comment: this might get closed but this is my opinion, baneling bash the wall followed with some lings then transition to mutas, if it doesnt ill add more.

Comment: The other question is from June last year. While it is basically the same question, the answers are way outdated, ZvP evolved a lot in that time.

Comment: @dbemerlin if you think it is out of date, consider updating it

Comment: You don't need to break his wall. FFE means he can't touch you for a very long time, and Zerg can get a strong 3-base economy in the time it takes Protoss to even put pressure on you. The moment you see a FFE, take an immediate third base (usually around 24 supply), and build queens and drones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to beat FFE is not to all-in or go for early aggression (which **can** work but is gimmicky and not reliable) but to expand faster yourself. Think about what your opponent **can't** do when he FFEs... correct, punish you for greed.

Take for example games of stephano where he gets his third as early as 4:30 and that way has a far stronger economy that allows him to just overwhelm his opponent with the sheer number of roaches whenever the Protoss tries to be aggressive.

The usual followup to that is to tech up to hive and break the wall with infestor/broodlord/corruptor.

Take a look at this Day9 episode which - while focussed more on lategame - still shows some early/midgame stuff.

http://blip.tv/day9tv/day-9-daily-429-p1-stephano-s-zvp-late-game-style-6009413

Answer (score 1):

It'll take a while before the Forge-fast-expander gets his army up to snot. This gives you plenty of time to expand and tech. Muta harass is always a good option, and Muta-ling is a real pain to deal with as Protoss.